# Rename Directory With SubFolders and Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory, .net

How can I rename a directory which has many folders and files underneath it? Directory.Move() keeps throwing errors and I read that you cannot use it on non-empty Directories.

Comment: What errors? There's not much to go on here.

Comment: Where did you read it can't be used on non-empty directories? Are you handling the exception? If so, what is the exception?

Comment: As others have said you need to add more info, there is nothing in the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx) which says it can't be used on a non-empty directory but there are a number of documented errors that can be thrown e.g. trying to move a directory to a path that already exists.  With more detail people could actually give you a useful answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always execute the REN command line method:

```
REN Dir1 Dir2
```

You could also try:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Dir1"));
di.MoveTo(Server.MapPath("Dir2"));
```

Here is a rough C# version of using the REN method:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\\Temp";
        Process oProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);

        oProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"Echo on");
        oProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"ren ~test2 ~test1");
        oProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"EXIT");
        string output = oProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        oProcess.WaitForExit();

        Console.Write(output);

        oProcess.Close();
```

Comment: @TravisJ: Updated with a C# mechanism for using the ren method.

Comment: Thank you very much, the suggestion to use DirectoryInfo along with MapPath worked very nicely and I appreciate the help!